# API 28 ONLY - Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: android

I have an issue that I cant seem to solve as it only seems to happen on API 28 (Android 9). Every time I log in on my app on my device I get this error and I've no idea why or how to fix it as it only seems to happen on this API. I'm finding the stack trace hard to follow and unsure how to locate the root of the problem.

I will post the stack trace but I'm not sure what other files to include so if you think you know where the issue might be please ask and I will post the relevant files that you need.

Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{grouppay.dylan.com.grouppay/grouppay.dylan.com.activities.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:543)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at grouppay.dylan.com.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:63)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class TextView
 Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
 2019-05-10 16:08:04.130 13315-13315/grouppay.dylan.com.grouppay E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:107)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:383)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3917)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1258)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1112)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:98)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:94)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:215)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:285)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:197)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:543)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at grouppay.dylan.com.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:63)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Home activity with all relevant NavDrawer code:

```
public ActiveAccountsRVAdapter adapter;
List<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView accountsRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager accountsRecyclerViewLayoutManager;
private TextView noAccountsTextView, navName, navEmail;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;
private String userId, userName, userEmail, profileImgUrl;
private int numberOfActiveGroups;
private GroupAccountAPI apiInterface;
private ImageView navDrawerProfileImage, noAccountsImgView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");
userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
profileImgUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("profileImgUrl");

setUpFAB();
setUpAccountPreviewRecyclerView();
//noAccountsTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.noAccountPreviewsTextView);

pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.homePullToRefresh);
pullToRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent);
pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new 
SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
  @Override
  public void onRefresh() {
    setUpAssociatedAccountsCall(userId);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
      }
    },4000);
  }
});

drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, 
R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);

drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

setUpActionBar();
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

setUpNavDrawer();
```

}

```
private void setUpNavDrawer() {
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
navName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.navName);
navEmail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.navEmail);
navName.setText(userName);
navEmail.setText(userEmail);
navDrawerProfileImage = (ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerProfileImage);
if(profileImgUrl != null) {
  Glide.with(navDrawerProfileImage.getContext())
      .load(profileImgUrl)
      .into(navDrawerProfileImage);
} else {
  navDrawerProfileImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_profile_photo));
}
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.nav_profile:
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(Home.this, Profile.class);
        profileIntent.putExtra("userId", userId);
        startActivityForResult(profileIntent, 100);
        break;
      case R.id.nav_cards:
        Intent intentPaymentMethods = new Intent(Home.this, PaymentMethods.class);
        intentPaymentMethods.putExtra("userIdStr", userId);
        startActivityForResult(intentPaymentMethods, 120);
        break;
      case R.id.nav_transactions:
        Intent intentTransactions = new Intent(Home.this, AllTransactions.class);
        intentTransactions.putExtra("userIdStr", userId);
        intentTransactions.putExtra("numberOfGroups", String.valueOf(groupAccounts.size()));
        startActivity(intentTransactions);
        break;
      case R.id.nav_logout:
        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intentLogin);
        break;
      default:
        return true;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

}

Home XML Container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/whiteText"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/activity_home_main_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAddAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/whiteText"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/homeFAB"
            app:borderWidth="1dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus_icon_blue" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/home_nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_home_nav_drawer_header"
        android:id="@+id/navView">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the code for the class with the navigation view in it, also maybe the layout file

Comment: @CCT Sure, will edit now

Comment: I'm thinking delete api28 and reinstall it.

Comment: @danny117 This happens multiple devices with API 28 so I don't think that will do the trick..